# Could answering with the same link-only answer be considered spam?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, spam, link-only-answers, self-promotion

I was reviewing the low quality posts queue and I've seen 6 or 7 times (until now) the same answer from the same user, an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18055933

The answer is this:

> You can use the below API to get the list of files without limit. If you like, please give a star to the repository.
>
> https://github.com/[user]/[project]

All the questions are about AWS S3 presigned URL limit, whatever it mean (I don't know anything about AWS), so the answers seem to be relevant because they link to a repository related to that, although they are low quality being link-only.

But the user is also requesting a vote up in GitHub, which seems like self-promotion.

For now I'm just flagging them as low quality and raised a custom flag in one on them explaining the situation, just to err on the safe side.

Should be this considered as spam? Or just a long string of low quality answers?

Comment: *raised a custom flag in one on them explaining the situation*, yep, this. It's perfect what you've done. What that user is doing is called excessive self promotion. Don't go to mass spam flag all these, just cusflag them. Mods will delete it all and send them a strong message.

Comment: @BhargavRao please note that github user owning advertised repo has the same name and photo as the answerer but affiliation is not disclosed in the example answer. I think this qualifies as spam - https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @gnat ah, yes. I actually saw that after writing the comment. Undisclosed over self promotion *is* spam. However, in these cases, a custom flag along with a spam flag is helpful, because we can send them a message pointing them to the rules. (In many cases, user's aren't aware of the rule, and one nudge in the right direction would make them correct themselves)

Comment: So it seems that custom flags its the way to go for more things that I though, glad to have did the right thing. Besides this, I like the option of giving a warning to the user before escalating the situation (the user has about 70 rep so he have contributed to SO).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Great, it seems you've done **exactly what you're supposed to do**. If you suspect something is spam, but it's not immediately obvious, it's better to use a custom moderator flag than a straight spam flag, which has no options to clarify your reasoning (relevant [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301835/295232)).

As @gnat noted, the avatar gave away that this user is the *author* of the promoted GitHub repository, which is a requirement for something to be considered spam:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](/help/promotion).

In general, as a community member, you should focus on moderating *posts*, which is exactly what the VLQ and NAA flags are for. ♦ moderators have the means to investigate *users*, e.g. find out if this is just an enthusiastic 'consumer' of this API, or one of the authors/close affiliates, and take the appropriate measures.

Comment: That is more or less what I supposed but I'm wanted to be sure, also I find helpful your clarification about who has to focus on posts and users.

Comment: @Glorfindel: you _know_ that you cannot ping users with @ in answers right ? :)

Comment: Yes. It wasn't my intention to ping him, I just needed to give him credit.

Comment: *"Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation."* So if the author's affiliation *is* disclosed, it's not spam?

Comment: It’s one of the conditions for a post *not* being spam. If you post nothing but answers promoting your product, even with disclosure, it still reeks of spam and in most cases you’re stopped by the moderators.

Comment: *"As @gnat notes, the avatar gives away that this user is the author of the promoted GitHub repository"* It [doesn't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212325/karthikeyan-govindaraj) (as of this writing), unless you visually extract `gkarthiks` from the middle of the lib URL and assume it relates to the user name `Karthikeyan Govindaraj` (fairly subtle). Which is why I, for one, don't think disclosure only in your username or avatar is sufficient; at one stroke, you can remove that disclosure from hundreds or even thousands of posts.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's pretty clearly stated (to me at least) in [promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) that *you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.* So I'd say no one has a place to claim that a username or avatar is sufficient disclosure.

Comment: @CalvT븃: Actually I think I've seen something from someone at SE saying *exactly* that (username or avatar is sufficient), but I don't have it to hand. I hope I'm mistaken about that.